# Run a line of VBA code from within Python using win32com

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

Rather than running a macro already built into an Excel spreasheet, I would like to run a single line of code. For example:

```
import os
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename='foo.xlsx')

xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname")  # what I can do

xl.Application.RunLine('ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties("Project Title") = "Category A"')  # this is what I want to do instead

xl.Application.Save()
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.

Comment: I don't have Sharepoint so can't test ContentTypeProperties. Typically you should be able to control the workbook object directly. `wb=xl.Workbooks.Open(...)` followed by `wb.ContentTypeProperties('Project Title').Value = 'Category A'`

Comment: @DS_London that seems to help, the only issue is that the `wb.ContentTypeProperties('Project Title')` returns None, I'm assuming this is because I need to instantiate the contenttypeproperty. Any idea on how to do that? `ContentTypeProperties.Add()` throws an attribute error. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard for me to say. As I understand it, these properties are added to Sharepoint documents. As I don't use Sharepoint, trying to access the ContentTypeProperties just yields the error: `This document must contain Content Type properties. Content Type properties are a common requirement for files in a document management system.`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.contenttypeproperties
 and then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.metaproperties  Doesn't look like the collection has an Add() method.

Comment: @DS_London I was able to update it according to your advice. The reason is was not working was that I first passed a property called `Title` which returned None. Trying my exact title provided `Project Title`, works